# Jetpack Compose - TopAppBar bottom line

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have TopAppBar:

```
   MaterialTheme {
    TopAppBar(
        backgroundColor = colorResource(
            id = if (isSearchOn == true) {
                R.color.white
            } else {
                R.color.blue
            }
        ),
        title = {
            if (isSearchOn == true) {
                TextField()
            }
        },
        navigationIcon = {
            BackButton()
        },
        contentColor = colorResource(
            id = if (isSearchOn == true)
                R.color.grey else
                R.color.white
        ),
    )
}
```

It looks as expected but the only thing which is missing is bottom line below it. I think usually it's achieved by adding elevation to it. I tried to add elevation but it doesn't change anything. the background of it is white and the background below is white as well and it doesn't look like a toolbar. Is there a way to add it explicitly?

Comment: The `TopAppBar` has a default elevation of `4.dp`

Comment: Maybe your `R.color.white` is not really that white? even default `elevation` should work fine with `Color.White`.

Comment: Do you have the same issue using your `TopAppBar` with a `Scaffold`?

Comment: yes. I posted my solution in the answer below. Looks to me like a interior issue between xml and composeView

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `Surface()` that servers as a parent for your `TopAppBar` to achieve `elevation`. The default `AppBar()` *composable* has that not.

My suggestion would be something like this:

```
) { //upper end of something else
    Surface(elevation = 8.dp) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(56.dp)
                .background(color = background),
            )
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but wrapping TopAppBar with Surface(elevation = 8.dp) didn't change anything visually.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem and here are my thoughts on this:

My TopAppBar is inside ComposeView which was added to xml layout. TopAppBar takes all the height of the view and since the next view below TopAppBar is xml view, the elevation of compose view cannot be applied on xml view.
So I end up adding Spacer below the TopAppBar

Here is my working solution of composable:

```
MaterialTheme {
  Column {
    TopAppBar(
        backgroundColor = colorResource(
            id = if (isSearchOn == true) {
                R.color.white
            } else {
                R.color.blue
            }
        ),
        title = {
            if (isSearchOn == true) {
                TextField()
            }
        },
        navigationIcon = {
            BackButton()
        },
        contentColor = colorResource(
            id = if (isSearchOn == true)
                R.color.grey else
                R.color.white
        ),
    )
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
}
```